# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{k^2-1}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Is the following series convergent or divergent? And how can I prove it? Which theorem should I use?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{k}{k^2-10}$$

Comment: comparison criterion with a well-known divergent series

Comment: Best is Comparison. But you can use the Integral Test, since $\int_4^\infty \frac{x}{x^2-4}\,dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: when $k$ is large, $\displaystyle\frac{k}{k^2-10} \geq \frac{k}{k^2}$.

Comment: and since $\frac{k}{k^2}$ is divergent, so is $\frac{k}{k^2-10}$ right?

Comment: @Bonnie yes, comparison test

Comment: i always tried do find a function bigger. I forgot that i could proof it like that way :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to use the asymptotic comparison with the harmonic series:

$$\frac{k}{k^2-10}\sim_\infty\frac1k$$
or a simple comparison:
$$\frac{k}{k^2-10}\ge\frac1k$$

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Integral Test

$$ \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{1}^b \frac{x}{x^2 - 1}\text{d}x$$

would lead to

$$\frac{1}{2} ln ({x^2-1}) $$

then just evaluate from b(infinity) to 1.

You will then see that the series diverges.